# unreachable char array not gc'ed in full gc

Tags: java, memory-management, garbage-collection

In one of our java applications, we are seeing frequent Full GCs. 2 per second.

Majority of heap space >90% attributed to char array allocations. 
On heap dump analysis, all are found to be unreachable under the GC roots but don't seem to be collected by the garbage collector. char arrays are only used in one place in our code in a method scope for IO.

We have the default young to tenured ratio (1:3) and default GC algo.
I did not alter this, as this application was running fine with 1G heap for a long time and now suddenly even 4G is not sufficing.

My biggest pain point is the 90% tenured memory allocated to the char arrays, which should have been ZERO. Does anyone have any clue as to what could be wrong here or leads on how I can debug it further?
I seem to be blank at it

UPDATE 1:
During heap analysis, I could see the largest char arrays, and hence point out exactly in the code where those arrays are being allocated. We are trying to read clobs fron DB, around 100K in size, while in the heap dump, the same arrays are  found to be around 100MB in size[I am still delving around this. Will update if I find anything]

The reason I am saying these arrays are not reachable beacuse I can see them under the GC roots, under the unreachable heads. Please correct me if there is anything wrong in assuming this.

[image]

[image]

This is the code which is used to read clobs from DB.

```
String readFromRSClobStream(Reader reader, int buffersize) throws Exception {       
        String result="";
        char[] buffer=new char[buffersize];
        int count=0;
        while((count=reader.read(buffer))!=-1)
        {
            String buffer_str=new String(buffer);
            result+=buffer_str.substring(0,count);
        }
        return result;
    }
```

The leak suspect view however gives me this
[image]

The char[] and the String both pertaining to the one's in the above code.

P.S.
Wish I could share the complete hprof

Comment: [**Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed in this link**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Questions that *lack sufficient information to diagnose the problem.* Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself.

Comment: I can guarantee you that if the char arrays are in regular heap and are unreachable they would be GCed.  (And saying that "char arrays are only used in one place in our code" is naive beyond belief.  Would you have us believe that your app contains no Strings?)

Comment: I'm not familiar with that instrumentation.  What reasons does the documentation give for an object being listed as "unreachable"?  (Note that the "loaded by system class loader" message is a red herring -- it just says these are system classes, which is true of all arrays.)

Comment: The fact that this appears to be related to DB (and CLOBs in particular) would suggest some sort of problem with the use of the DB interfaces.  Commonly buffers are allocated in Java, then passed to the native code to fill.  If the wrong protocols are used (either in your code or the native code) then the buffers might not be released on the JNI side and this could happen.

Comment: Have you examined the actual byte values stored in any of these arrays?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of three possible explanations:

- You are mistaken in your heap dump analysis, and the arrays are in fact reachable.
- These large character arrays are normally reachable via a soft or weak reference, and there is some "phasing" effect going on here.  (It typically takes 2 or more GC cycles to reclaim objects that are referred to by a soft/weak reference.  If you look at the heap *after* the reference has been broken by the GC, it will contain all of the previously referenced objects ... as unreachable.
- You are allocating the arrays at a excessive rate and / or some of them are exceedingly large.  A high rate of object allocation would typically result in lots of young space collections.  However, if you allocate "really large" objects (or arrays), the allocator on some JVMs will put the new objects straight into tenured space.  Too much of that could trigger frequent full GCs.

(Of course, it could be something else entirely, but you haven't given us much evidence to work with.)

Reference: ["Size Matters"](https://blogs.oracle.com/jonthecollector/entry/size_matters) by Jon Masamitsu's @ Oracle.

---

**UPDATE**

Your `readFromRSClobStream` method is likely to be inefficient and to generate lots of garbage, especially if `bufferSize` is small relative to the CLOB size.  Each time you do the string concatenation, you are creating a new String and copying the contents of the old String and the characters from `buffer` into it.  That gives you `O(N^2)` copied characters and `O(N)` object allocations.

Hence, if the CLOB you are reading is really large, you will get lots of really large `char[]` objects allocated, and that is (IMO) the likely cause of the GC indigestion.

A much more efficient way would be something like this:

```
String readFromRSClobStream(Reader reader, int clobSizeHint, int bufferSize) 
       throws IOException {       
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(clobSizeHint);
    char[] buffer = new char[buffersize];
    int count = 0;
    while ((count = reader.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        sb.append(buffer, 0, count);
    }
    return sb.toString;
}
```

If the size hint is correct (i.e. it is the actual CLOB size in characters), this gives you `O(N)` copied characters and `O(1)` object allocations.

Even if the size hint is inaccurate (but not wildly too large) you get `O(N)` copied characters and `O(logN)` allocations or better.  (This is down to `StringBuilder` using a strategy of at least doubling its internal buffer size each time it fills up.)

Comment: The most likely "real" leak scenario would be some sort of I/O buffer, attached to an I/O object which is not correctly closed before being collected.  Otherwise I'd suspect either "misleading" instrument readings or failure to clear links in some sort of large linked data structure.

Comment: Well I must admit I am overwhelmed by the response. Thank you all for responding.
I dont claim to be an expert here and my interpretations could be wrong. I have updated the question with more information.Let me know if you want me to share other views of the heap.
Please be specific because there are a lot of these views.

Comment: @Stephen C : Yes, we do allocate arrays, few of the order of 100KB and your third point was our best guess before increasing the heap from 1G to 4G. But I fear increasing the heap further 
would only hide the real problem instead of fixing it.

Comment: @HotLicks: For the char arrays, I could not say decisively from the dump analysis that it was showing me the char arrays associated with the Strings, hence I mentioned otherwise. 
I presume that would go under String allocation. Please correct me if I am wrong. And regarding your second comment, that is something, if present, would happen consistently, 
not suddenly after an year of the application being deployed.

Comment: @rohitwali - The failure to clear links is something that could happen due to a "trivial" modification, even one in some 3rd party code.

Comment: And certainly the readFromRSClobStream method is poorly written.